# How to control what fields there are in the address pop-up?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm configuring CRM 2013 for a client and they are very strong on not showing the state field. However, on the form, I only see *Address 1*. When I access the page as a user, when I try to enter the data, there are five or six fields in the pop-up, though.

How can I get rid of that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business Rule (new 2013 functionality):

- no condition - fire always
- Action:  Address1: State/Province - Hide field

or

Get into unsupported jscript and try to hide it.

Comment: So, just to verify - there's no **supported** way to get rid of it, correct? We can only hide it so it **looks** like if it's gone?!

Comment: Business rule is supported. Currently there's no way to modify composite controls, other then hide a unwanted bits. There's no way to add other address fields for example.

Comment: I've tried the exact thing and, as I understand, it's supposed to work like that. However, in my case, it doesn't for some reason. Something I've missed - I've asked a new question on the subject. You're free to take a look [over there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835980/fields-not-being-hidden-despite-a-business-rule?lq=1) and scratch your head too.   :)

Comment: See my comment on new question - when you try to hide non-exiting field, all fails without warning orerror

Comment: By `unsupported` JavaScript we mean code that is not sustainable and bound to this version of MS CRM only. Usually such JS code works on DOM level directly — manipulating HTML form contents. In case if HTML will change radically the JS will stop working.