# Fields not being hidden despite a business rule

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821959/how-to-control-what-fields-there-are-in-the-address-pop-up/25824205#25824205) I verified that the correct approach for hiding some individual fields from a composite field is done correctly. That seems to be confirmed by other sources as well. However, despite a rule defined like so:

[image]

I still get the stupid fields to show up when on account form. It looks as the following image depicts and is a high level annoyance and reason for my teeth grinding. What am I missing? (Yes, I did activate the rule and I reloaded the form.)

[image]

Comment: Didn't tested, but i think county is not on the form and makes all actions fails. If there are any issues with Business rule (i.e. try to hide field NOT present on the form), It wouldn't complain by throwing any errors

Comment: Oh, you mean that a field contained in the composite box doesn't count as "being on the form" unless it's contained as a simple field as well? That's both confusing and impractical. Also, I don't feel convenient with the limitations of the composite atrocity. I think they should either allow for full customization (allowing to design custom controls) or get rid of the sucker all together...

Comment: I mean county is not even in the composite. And i agree, that composites are good idea, but they need some improvements.

Comment: I've had issues where hidden fields were the first field on the form and the method the MS uses to select the first field, made it visible.  This isn't happening in your case is it?

Comment: @MarioZG POst your comments as a reply. It's a good answer. As for the error reported, see my comment to Daryl below. You might want to include that in the reply as well for other souls to enjoy and use. I mean - *county* is there, if you don't get hung up on a single "r". Come on - don't be a nit-pick, hihi.

Comment: @Daryl This was a very good guess. There might be another script doing something unexpected. However, this particular issue is purely linguistic. See, some idiot chose to call *country* and *county* way too similar for a tired code monkey to tell apart. I had added the rule to **county** instead of **country** an just didn't see it. Good thing Mario-dude had keen eyes (or, likely, made the same stupid mistake right before, hahaha).

Comment: @KonradViltersten county-countRy and contact-contRact are my favorites in CRM :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are any issues with business rule (i.e. when attempting to hide a field **not** present on the targeted form, as is the case, due to mix-up between **country** and **county**), it wouldn't proceed, the execution will stop but there won't be any complaints or any errors thrown.

Credits to @Daryl for: "*I've had issues where hidden fields were the first field on the form and the method the MS uses to select the first field, made it visible.*"

Comment: Took the liberty to reformulate from great to perfect.   :)